# How to prevent Slidy from advancing on click

Tags: datatable, r-markdown, slidy

I have an rmarkdown document that I am attempting to update to a slidy presentation.  I have been able to produce usable reports in this slidy presentation, however, when I click on one of the filters in the datatable, from the datatable package, it advances to the next slide.  This is undesirable and I was curious if there was a way to disable this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

To toggle on/off this option in Slidy you just click `k` letter in the keyboard! Its pretty handy!

**Tip:** click `h` letter (alias for help) in the keyboard to check more available instructions too!! ;-)